# Is this an example of Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, thought-experiment

I recently read about an example of the correlation between position and momentum measurements and how one's precision leads to inaccuracy in the measurement of the other variable. Suppose there is an hydrogen atom in the ground state .We project quite a few photon towards the atom so that it gets reflected by the electron and we get some information about its position,(the chances of the desired collision are very less because there is a massive nucleus but nevertheless..

.We know about the energy gaps between the different shells.So if I were to project a photon of considerable energy,an electron in the ground state will reflect it instead of absorbing it and jumping to higher energy orbitals. Considering collision of two photons one with nucleus and other with electron,we might get the position of electron w.r.t nucleus.

For some higher n, say n=4 we are limited to use very low I.R. radiations (so that the electron reflects the photon instead of absorbing it), and acc to me low frequency will give less detailed information about the position of electron but since this photon has less momentum, the momentum of electron after collision would be a lot easier to predict than the first case.

Is this an example of Heisenberg's principle or there are some flaws in my understanding that I can't see right now(Disclaimer:-I have a very rough idea about how low frequency of light= less information of position)

Comment: A wave can't be smaller much more than half of the wavelength, meaning IR photons which have a wavelength longer than a micron, can't have a size comparable to an atom

Comment: Oh Thanks for pointing out, then instead of taking n=4,we can take n=2 for a  heavier cation like K(18+) for which the energy gap between n=2 and n=3 is large enough so that wavelength associated with it is comparable to the size of an atom